# HttpContext in ashx handlers load balancing

Tags: c#, asp.net, handler

I use handler(.ashx) to display images on a webpage.Code which looks like

```
  Image1.ImageUrl="Imagehandler.ashx?id="+2
```

This works fine in dev environment as well as production when there is single server.
But has a problem with load balanced multiple web servers.

Handler code looks like this

```
 ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
 {
   int id=int.parse(context.Request.Querystring["abc"]);
 }
```

I have a suspicion that this context has a problem when sometimes handler request hits another server.If I switch off one server on production then It starts to work well.

Has anybody come across this? and any thought?

Comment: Are you using State server or using InProc session storage?

Comment: "has a problem" did not give any clue about the issue, and even you can not solve it if you do not identify "the problem". By the way the code you have here has no issue at all - only if you use session you may have some problem that i can think of.

Comment: In Proc sessions. do you mean if a page is loading on one server, and handler request to another, there would not be a problem with context.Querystring[""] ?

Comment: The querystring, has nothing to do with session, and handler also did not attached to the session by default.